# HTTP vs HTTPS requests with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm working on REST API client for Android using Retrofit.
Some of the use something like this `http://my.backend.com` and others use `https://my.backend.com`. The way I found is to create two separate interfaces and build two RestAdapters with different endpoints.
But I would like to keep my interfaces consitent and I'm wondering if it is possible for example build my Res adapter with `my.backend.com` and specify if the methot thould use https with `@HTTPS` annotation ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can change on a `RestAdapter` after it's been built is the [log level](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.html#setLogLevel-retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel-) so I'm afraid the only solution is to have two `RestAdapter`s. Two seperate interfaces should not be necessary though, as long as the path after your endpoint (my.backend.com) is the same for both the http and the https version.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following generic method which returns retrofit and keep just one interface. "baseUrl" can be either "http" or "https" urls.

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofit(@NotNull String baseUrl) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```